# Date Picker for iPhone Web Application

Tags: datepicker, iphone

What is best way to show Date Picker for iPhone based Web Application. Can we show something like iPhone native date picker like shown below in web application:

[image: iOS Date Picker]

Comment: Please adjust the answer to one more appropriate.    We dont need an external package that cubiq uses, where as there is an easier way.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The easiest way (and arguably the best way) is to use safari's built in datepicker for your input box using HTML5 type="date"

```
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: This just saved me SO much time and effort, it felt great to just stick this on my site and watch the nifty little date picker appear on my iPhone.

Comment: And what about dropping it down when type="date" doesnt work? e.g. responsive site design?

Comment: i wish i saw this before i wrote a plugin.  SUch a waste of a few days or work.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution to `datetime`, you're better off creating separate `date` and `time` inputs.

Comment: Don't forget about `month` type if you are looking for month selector.

Answer (score 36):

There is an iPhone native style date picker that runs in the browser - http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch/11

Comment: In iOS5, you can use <input type="date" /> (see the answer by Kyle Gibbens), which will bring up the native date picker in Mobile Safari or in a webview.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's an old post, but for future viewers:
If you are using jQuery, you can try [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com), a customizable datepicker optimized for touch devices. It ships whith iOS and android skin as well.

Comment: @Tom, it does not require jQuery Mobile, requires jQuery, Zepto.js or App Framework

Comment: Very true, I'm using it now! I'll remove my comment.

Comment: FYI, It's not free.

Comment: @azerafati At the time of the answer it was. Here's the link to the last free version https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll/tree/v2.17.3

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The date picker is a native control and is not available in Mobile Safari.

Comment: +1 as technically correct. You can't trigger the native date picker from the browser (which is a complete oversight on Apple's part, IMHO). The chosen answer is correct, as well, in that you can write JavaScript to emulate it.

Comment: you can. By using UIWebView's javascript bridge

Comment: type="datetime-local" works on iOS7 (they removed "datetime" for whatever reason)

Comment: datetime-local does not support year for some twisted reason! only on iOS. If it is dec 31 and I'm planning something for next week? good luck for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Although the need to register might be a dislike, [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/component/datetime) looks worth evaluating if you want to provide a consistent fallback for older ios (pre 5.x) and android (pre 4.x) devices - and probably some other platforms, as it promises to support jQMobi (now Intel appframework) and Zepto.

Answer (score 1):

There is an iPhone style date picker for HTML5 at [Next-Point](http://www.next-point.ro/Transport/App/Adauga). Maybe you can change it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could code your own if it was really important to you.

With enough work you could probably get it to look/feel a lot like Apple's native control.

Feels at a gut level like it would be a lot of work for limited payoff.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date" />
```

above code WILL NOT working on mozilla.

firefox doesn't support input type date.

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.Net you can use the TextBox with type="date".

```
<asp:TextBox type="date" runat="server" />
```

In a Html5 compatible browser you will have a date field.
In a Html5 non-compatible browser you will have simple text field.