# How to use Same Date picker for both Android and Iphone?

Tags: cordova, datepicker, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an application in Android and Iphone using Phonegap Api. My application contains Date fields. So i searched for date picker plugin for both android and iphone. I found date picker plugin in this link for Android.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker

and for Iphone

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/DatePicker

here my doubt is how to use these two, to support Date picker in both Android and iPhone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android

Answer (score 0):

Use Mobi Scroll for Android and IOS