# XPages mobile web application ; input time with iPhone

Tags: iphone, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm making a mobile web application with the extension library in XPages. The user has to make some inputs. One of those is time. I would like the user to get the native spinning time scroller from the iPhone. Instead he gets an unusable time "choser". How could I do this? Now I'm using standard code like: (code is for a date but problem remains the same)

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.visDate}" id="visDate1" 
defaultValue="#{javascript:@Now()}" style="width:100px">
  <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
     <xp:this.converter>
    <xp:convertDateTime type="date">
    </xp:convertDateTime>
     </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Check out question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android there is a good explanation when iPhones use there native date/time Picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `type` property of edit box to `time`, something like this:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" type="time"></xp:inputText>
```

The `type` property supports quite a few other values. Have a look in the All Properties tab for edit box. But I doubt the value stored would be in `NotesDateTime` format.