# UIWebView DatePicker Input Detection

Tags: ios, uiwebview, datepicker

I have a `UIWebView` and I'd like to use the internal datepicker on *iOS* that is used when I have the `<input type=date>` tag.

I have some UIViews in *iOS* that I want to modify based on if that input changes.

How do I detect this change?  I'm hoping there is a delegate I can use but based on my research, that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to catch datepicker value changed event? If it is, you can simply create IBAction method and connect it to datepicker valueChanged event in interface builder.

Comment: I don't think this works for UIWebViews.  How do you get an IBAction for a datepicker that doesn't exist yet?  It won't exist until you click on an input field in the UIWebView.

Comment: after showing datepicker call
[picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dofreakysheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]

Answer (score 2):

This may can help you

[Invoke native date picker from web-app on iOS/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android)

There are some plugins that simulates the uidatepicker style in javascript.