# jQuery datepicker Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm developing a jQuery Mobile application.
How can I add the Click Event of a

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

to a link. So that when the link is clicked the datepicker will appear.

[Like in the image but without the input-Field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4czi2.jpg)

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? We need a little bit more to go on to help you out.

Comment: I tried to trigger the click, onclick events when the input field is onfocus but it didn't work.