# how to change my date picker show in only month,date and year

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

The default UIDatePicker shows both the date and time. I need to show only the month, day and year like this:

[image]

How can I change the picker to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the date pickers mode.

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

"Date" is also an option in the inspector in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the page where the second image is there ?

[Date Picker for iPhone Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388814/date-picker-for-iphone-web-application)

seems like it has answer to your question!

Comment: illa tamil they added for web application i need only normal application like calculator.

Answer (score 0):

[UIDatePicker Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) Refer this