# how to change input type of jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am not sure if I wrote the right title but..

I am using jQuery Datepicker,it works just fine, but **on iphone** as you click on input area to choose a date it brings calender which is good but it brings up **keyboard** too and calender stays under the keyboard..

How can I change it so that as you click on input area it brings up only datepicker calender and not the text keyboard..

How I use it:

```
 <input type="text" id="from" class="datePicker" name="from" placeholder="Select Date">
```

I hope that my question is clear..

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting the textbox read only property to true? Using `readonly="true"`

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388814/date-picker-for-iphone-web-application

Comment: I've added it as an answer if you would like to accept it, I would greatly appreciate it. Cheers. Glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the readonly property of your textbox to true, thus eliminating the input field so that the phone only recognises it as the datepicker you have defined it as. This will make sure the phone doesnt display a keyboard.