# Scroll through dates using a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I've build a carousel that will let users flick/scroll trough dates using the slick library. I've got some minor issues with the library, and a major one.

You can see the carousel here:
http://radiant-meadow-8480.herokuapp.com/

user=test,

pw=test

I'll list the issues in the hopes that you can help me fix them, but if not, it might help you recommend me another library.

1. Events only fire when you release you're click(mouse up). I would like to slide my finger/mouse back and forth, and see the data on the screen change.
2. You can't sling your finger/mouse to one side and scroll through a bunch of slides. You'll only slide though a few slides.

The biggest issue is the fact that the slide your currently looking at will change, if you add slides in front of it. To get past this you have to destroy the slick object, and reinitialize it. This makes it way less smooth, and close to unusable on my old iPhone 3g.

I don't have any easily sharable code, but I hope the demo on the page, plus my issues listed can help you recommend a better suited library, or a fix to my current implementation.

I've also looked at iScroll, but the infinity scroll gave me nothing but problems, and the documentation seemed a bid lacking. It's also my understanding that the author is working on an updated version, and haven't updated the current release for over 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

I would go one step out and question your usage of a carousel at all.

Why?

1. If you are doing mobile development, just allow mobile devices to use their built in ones, e.g. for iPhone use

   `<input type="date"/>`

   See [Date Picker for iPhone Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388814/date-picker-for-iphone-web-application).
2. Carousels for date selection on desktop are kludgy at best, including this one.
3. Carousels (although yours is slightly different) are generally considered bad UI. This is more of a slider than a carousel, granted. Reference:

Humorous example:
http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Good explanation:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I actually came across most of the links you posted doing my research, but kind of disregarded them, because my use seemed different. I'll take a closer look at <input type="date"/>. I came across this app as well, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGWp57xtc10. And really liked the date-scroll-thing you can see 30sec in. I haven't tried the app, but the add shows what I was trying to create.

Comment: If you find that it doesn't meet your requirements, then the Date Picker link has some suggestions on other libraries to use. Good luck :)