# How do I show a place holder in the date field and make it work in iOS Safari,

Tags: javascript, html, safari, datepicker

In most browsers I can do the following

```js
const x = document.getElementById("asdf");
x.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  x.type = 'date'
})
x.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  x.type = 'text'
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="asdf" placeholder="foop" />
```

However on mobile Safari it does not show the [proper date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388814/date-picker-for-iphone-web-application#:%7E:text=The%20date%20picker%20is%20a%20native%20control,and%20is%20not%20available%20in%20Mobile%20Safari.) when I tap on the field.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Don't link to codepen when you can use a stack snippet.

Comment: It also doesn't work in Chrome on iOS, it reports "Script error" as soon as I run the code. I suspect this is related. But I can't bring up a real console to see the actual error.

Comment: it worked on the codepen

Answer (score 0):

The work around I eventually put in was to create two input fields

```js
const x = document.getElementById("asdf");
const y = document.getElementById("asdf-date");
x.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  x.style.display = "none";
  y.style.display = "initial";
  y.focus();
})
x.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  x.style.display = "initial";
  y.style.display = "none";
  x.value = y.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="asdf" placeholder="foop" />
<input type="text" id="asdf-date" style="display:none" placeholder="foop" />
```